# understanding functools.wraps

Tags: python

I am using Flask-RESTful and trying to have my REST endpoints using the technique showed [here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html)

The main code is

```
def authenticate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not getattr(func, 'authenticated', True):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        acct = basic_authentication()  # custom account lookup function

        if acct:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        restful.abort(401)
    return wrapper


class Resource(restful.Resource):
    method_decorators = [authenticate]   # applies to all inherited resources
```

I do the same way and it seems to work, but I am not sure what happens with `@wraps`?
It seems magic to me at the moment and I did not understand the following

a.) It seems function which is wrapped with `@wraps` is passed to the wrapper, then what is the wrapper returning?

*Possible answer*: Everything that was passed to the function initially?

If yes, how can I pass more information like the `acct` object with everything so that my function receives the account object and I don't have to do a database fetch for it?

**UPDATE**
Based on the example, my rest endpoint looks like

```
class UserResource(RestResource):
    def get(self, uuid):
        return {'method': 'get user -> ' + uuid}
```

and I call it like

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/validUUID
```

Now when my every request is authenticated, I see if a valid `acct` object exists and if it exists, I delegate the control to endpoint

**Question**:
Since I am actually making one database call to find out `acct` object, is it possible to pass in that to the endpoint when a valid `acct` is located?

This way two things happen
a.) I know the call is authenticated
b.) I reuse the `acct` object which I can use for my further work, rather than making the DB call again and get the `acct` object from validUUID again

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authenticate` is a decorator -- it takes a function and returns a modified version of that function (which is usually implemented by wrapping the function and wrapping it).

Now, the problem with wrappers is that they often don't act exactly like the original function in some ways -- they may be missing docstrings, have the wrong `__name__` (`wrapper` instead of what it should be called), and other blemishes. This might be important if some other code is using that extra information. `functools.wraps` is a simple function that adds this information from the original function (here, `func`) to the wrapper function, so it behaves more like the original function. (Technically, it is itself a decorator, which is the confusing part, but you don't have to worry about that detail. Just know that it is a nice tool that copies attributes from a wrapped function to a wrapper function).

Thus, when you write

```
new_function = authenticate(old_function)
```

or more commonly

```
@authenticate
def function(...)
```

`new_function` will look more like `old_function`.

Comment: Thanks @nneonneo, I just added **update**, to see if what I do is achievable, please let me know

Comment: I must confess that I don't quite understand what your update is asking.